# cron not working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: cron

I am trying to write my first cron job on a Raspberry Pi 2b, logged in under username `pi`.  Note that I am using cron.d not crontab.

The job is intended to write the time to a file named `cron.txt` located in the directory `/home/pi`.

The cron file is named `mycronjob` and is located in `/etc/cron.d/`
Itts line is:

```
        ***** /home/pi/scripts/cron.sh
```

cron.sh is located at /home/pi/scripts/ . This file, before it was made executable, contained

```
   #!/bin/sh
   Date >> /home/pi/cron.txt
```

I can manually execute the cron.sh file using the following:  ./cron.sh
Checking cron.txt shows that the date was added to the file.
Problem: The cron should run every minute and add a time to the file but it doesn’t work.  I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: This is not the site for this question, you should try it at https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your script works fine? I think to echo date in bash you should do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date) >> /home/pi/cron.txt
```

Is your Date some specific function or system variable?

Why do you have to use `/etc/cron.d/`? Scripts that are in `/etc/cron.d/` don't load environment variables, that is why you may experience problems running your scripts. This directory holds cron files created by package installation scripts.
Another problem is misconfig of your task, to run every minute it should be `*/1` at first place.

if you need environment variables to be loaded, **please use `/etc/crontab`**, as described here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Example to run every minute:

```
# in commandline run crontab, if necessary choose text editor 
crontab -e
# add new line to your cron: 
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/scripts/cron.sh
```

Oh, and please make sure your script is executable: `chmod a+x /home/pi/scripts/cron.sh`.

And just to be sure your cron daemon is not dead check if it is in processes:

```
ps -ef | grep cron
```

Comment: Just to let you know I got your suggestions and am working on them.  I will let you know how it works.

Comment: What should be the expected output for "ps -ef | grep cron" ?